# MySQL Workbench: how do I set up a MySQL server such that computers from a different network can connect to the server?

Tags: networking, mysql, port-forwarding

I know how to write SQL codes but I am new to MySQL Workbench and I am trying to set up a MySQL server such that my laptop from a different network can connect remotely to the server resided in another machine.

Is this possible ? And how can this be done ? I tried the Standard TCP/IP option in MySQL Workbench but it only worked when both computers are in the same network. Can someone kindly point me towards the right direction please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please explain a bit what do you mean by different network? From outside your home network, or still within your home/work network (same wifi / LAN)? If you need your MySQL server accessible from outside your home/work network, you need to do port forwarding (and this question probably should be tagged networking)

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I meant From outside my home network. What is port forwarding ?

Comment: From outside your home network, when you put your IP address, it is technically the IP address of your router/modem. You need to configure your router to forward any request to  the MysSQL port (3306?) to be forwarded to your server (in your internal home network - that has an Internal IP address that you cannot connect to without going past your router). Does this make sense?

Comment: Right. So I need to configure my router to forward request to my server, since the router is the middle man. I will look further into port forwarding topic online. If I still have question, i will come back to you. Thanks.

Comment: All the best. You can also use this site https://portforward.com/router.htm to find your router model and find the step by step instruction. You simply need to forward Port 3306 (TCP) to whatever internal IP (192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x) that you use and also to the same port (3306), and it will allow your laptop (or anyone else) connecting to port 3306 to get forwarded to your MySQL server. And just a side note since your MySQL Server will be then visible to ANYONE on the internet - please make sure you use a good password to secure it.

Comment: So after setting up port forwarding, I can just establish connection using "Standard TCP/IP option" or should I use "Standard TCP/IP option over SSH" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48258/discussion-between-darius-and-mynameisjeff).